# DNS zone transfer interval

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, solaris

I've never made a change to a DNS record before. In researching the DNS servers I inherited (Solaris 5.6 with BIND v9.2.3), I found that DNS_A (private) is the primary DNS server and it replicates to DNS_B and DNC_C (both public) via the zone's db file option:

`allow-transfer { 192.in.ter.nal; 173.ex.ter.nal; };`

The header from the zone file is:

```
@ IN SOA DNS_A.redacted.com. postmaster.redacted.com. (
    2013010401  ; serial
    300 ; refresh
    120 ; retry
    6048000 ; expire
    300 )   ; ttl
```

I understand that I have to increment the serial number when I make the change so that the secondary DNS servers recognize a change, but will my secondary DNS servers not look for a change until the "expire" time is reached? If that's specified in seconds, that's 70 days.

What do the `refresh`, `retry`, `expire`, and `ttl` times mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the serial value to send a notification to all your slave servers telling them that the zone just changed so they can get the update.

Here follows the meaning of these items:

- ttl: default time-to-live for cached entries, defines how long those entries should be considered fresh;
- refresh: the time used by slave to check for updates on master;
- retry: time between retries when slave fails to contact master after refresh time;
- expiry: indicates that the zone is no longer valid after this time, used by slave servers only.

More on: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/soa.html

Answer (score 1):

By default, on a dns serial change, the BIND master will notify all name servers defined in the NS records for the zone. From there, the slaves will contact the master to initiate a zone transfer.

Comment: To be more precise: it will by default notify all nameservers indicated by `NS` records EXCEPT the `SOA` `MNAME`.

Comment: Point taken @HåkanLindqvist